# Working in a git repository with separate product lines

Tags: git

So I've found myself in a project where there are two variants of a product in a git repository. They come from a common code base but now have separate branches for ProductA and ProductB with their own unique code. Bringing them together is a topic for another question. Right now I'm looking for a strategy on how to do work that can be merged into both branches without bringing changes from one Product into the other Product. Is there any way to introduce a branch for common code the way that master should be?

Update:
Both Products share a large percentage of code

Comment: Do they have a significant number of their files in common, even if with somewhat different contents?